# Quartus keeps closing on me

Tags: quartus

Every time I create a new project quartus just closes on me. no error message no new window somewhere else it just closes. It makes the new project, and I can restart the program and work on the project. But when I try to compile the project I get the following error:

```
*** Fatal Error: Access Violation at 0X00007FF43C3FF858
Module: quartus.exe
Stack Trace:

   0x45da63: QAccessible::queryAccessibleInterface + 0x33 
   0x46403c: QAccessible::setRootObject + 0x153c 
   0x4652e9: QAccessible::setRootObject + 0x27e9 
     0xa990: CreateStdAccessibleProxyW + 0x510 
    0x4d512: UiaReturnRawElementProvider + 0xf912 
    0xce7f9: UiaRegisterProviderCallback + 0x38d89 
    0x3f5d4: UiaReturnRawElementProvider + 0x19d4 
    0x3f156: UiaReturnRawElementProvider + 0x1556 
    0x3ee49: UiaReturnRawElementProvider + 0x1249 
    0x3ea29: UiaReturnRawElementProvider + 0xe29 
    0x1cdaf: Ordinal2555 + 0x1af 
    0x24b4c: IsIconic + 0x1bc 
    0xa76a3: KiUserCallbackDispatcher + 0x23 
     0x13b3: NtUserPeekMessage + 0x13 
    0x19f0e: PeekMessageW + 0x1ce 
    0x19e79: PeekMessageW + 0x139 
   0x132d77: QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents + 0x1c7 
    0x83564: QApplicationPrivate::translateTouchEvent + 0x884 
   0x10e439: QCoreApplication::processEvents + 0x49 
     0x4576: QUI_APP::process_cmdline_arguments_pre_main_wnd_create + 0x4c6 
     0x11d3: thr_qt_process_events + 0x43 
     0x54c3: flow_kill + 0x1653 
     0xcfeb: flow_get_flow_type + 0x1abb 
    0x1a30b: flow_execute + 0x2a4b 
    0x21c3e: flow_execute + 0xa37e 
    0x2275d: flow_get_compiler_tools + 0x2cd 
    0x16c83: flow_execute_custom + 0x6f3 
    0x178fd: flow_execute + 0x3d 
     0x7ff4: QUI_APP::on_start_flow + 0x364 
    0x468c5: QUI_APP::qt_static_metacall + 0xa5 
   0x11d699: QObject::event + 0xd9 
    0x21c8d: QApplication::event + 0x39d 
    0x228f5: QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper + 0xf5 
    0x25297: QApplication::notify + 0x17f7 
   0x10a7c1: QCoreApplication::notifyInternal + 0x71 
   0x10c7cb: QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents + 0x29b 
   0x1311de: QEventDispatcherWin32::event + 0x70e 
    0x11c4b: CallWindowProcW + 0x43b 
    0x10ea5: DispatchMessageW + 0x2b5 
   0x132f69: QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents + 0x3b9 
    0x83564: QApplicationPrivate::translateTouchEvent + 0x884 
   0x109cf0: QEventLoop::exec + 0x230 
   0x10e5ff: QCoreApplication::exec + 0xdf 

     0x4c78: msg_exe_fini + 0x58 
     0x53bc: msg_exe_fini + 0x79c 
     0x1584: MEM_SEGMENT_INTERNAL::~MEM_SEGMENT_INTERNAL + 0x194 
     0x5f9f: msg_exe_main + 0x8f 


    0x154df: BaseThreadInitThunk + 0xf 
     0x485a: RtlUserThreadStart + 0x2a 

End-trace

Quartus II 64-Bit Version 13.0.1 Build 232 06/12/2013 SJ Web Edition
Service Pack Installed:  1
```

I've tried uninstalling then reinstalling the program. I make sure not to save the files in the quartus app folder, it doesn't really change anything as it still crashes when I save under the app folder. I've tried checking the disk for corrupted files. My version of windows is up to date. the version of quartus I am using is 13.0 sp1.

Does anyone have any ideas of what is wrong and how to fix it. Or do I just need to uninstall it and reinstall it again and pray to the computer gods that it works?

Comment: always format printouts as "code" for readability ... did it for you

Comment: I don't think a reinstallation would fix it. Looks like something related to accessibility interfaces. You could try disabling this by going into quartus's installation folder, locating Qt's `plugins` folder, and removing accessibility plugin DLLs (e.g. in `plugins\\accessiblebridge` or similar).

Comment: Which Windows?  Is it listed as compatible?

Comment: If your using the same project file, you might have to rebuild it

Comment: @rdtsc I'm running Windows 11, which isn't the problem since I am also running Windows 11 on my laptop and Quartus runs fine on it.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I don't think that is the issue since it closes once I click ok when creating a new project. I can then restart quartus and open the file. But when I try to compile it it sends that code message and then shuts the program down.

Comment: If [Quartus does not claim compatibility with Windows 11](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/programmable/support-resources/design-software/os-support.html), then it *could* be the OS (it can't be ruled out.)

Comment: @rdtsc The reason I ruled it out is my laptop is running windows 11 and it runs Quartus just fine. It's just my desktop that is having issues. Since both machines are using the same OS I don't think it is the issue.